# PHP exec to kill linux process not working

Tags: php, linux, apache, kill

I'm trying to kill a process from php script, but it keeps failing

```
ps ax | grep 8648

 8648 ?        Ss     0:15 /usr/bin/php -f /home/whatever/websites/engine/shadow_engine/engine_SHDW_01.php -- --id=SHDW_01
 9226 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep 8648
```

my php script :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && strlen(trim($_GET['id'])) > 0){
    $killCommand = "kill {$_GET['id']}";
    exec($killCommand, $killOutput, $killStatus);

    if($killStatus === 0){
        echo "Process successfully killed";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to kill process";
    }
}
```

$killStatus always return 1 instead of 0 which means the exec command is failed, i have tried 'sudo kill {$_GET['id']}' or even 'sudo kill -9 {$_GET['id']}', but none of them works.

edit : httpd error log says 'sh: line 0: kill: (1707) - Operation not permitted'

Comment: Who's the owner of that process?

Comment: i started it with a php somescript.php

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying `sudo` inside your `exec()` it's not working because you are not providing the password. 
Try to **either** run the whole script with sudo:

```
sudo php -f yourscript.php
```

**OR** inside your script pipe the sudo password into the `sudo kill {$_GET['id']}`

PS: the `-9` may still be needed, I would suggest trying to kill the process first from your terminal as usual and see if it will work.

Comment: how to do it ? im trying to kill a remote process from an url